# After creating a database with Visual Studio, on SQL Server 2008, how do I create a form to query the data?

Tags: database, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I want to create a database in Visual Studio. I will be using SQL Server 2008.

After I create it, I want to lets say.. I have created a code

EG:

```
select *
From table x
where bus = @value
Group by timetable
```

How can I have a form field that I can enter the `@value` into and then it will give me the results?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question.  You have a data source (SQL Server database) and now you have to create the connection parameters.  This is called a *Connection String*.  The connection string is what an application uses to connect to an **instance\database** within a specific security context with specified credentials.

Then inside the application you can utilize [System.Data.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) namespace.  Here you will use the [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) class to connect to the data source and the [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) class to issue a command against the connection.  At the bottom of that page is a decent code snippet:

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = 
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                    reader[0], reader[1]));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

It utilizes a DataReader as opposed to a DataAdapter to retrieve data.  If you are just looking to do a `SELECT` against the database a `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` call will be sufficient.

That's a start, but it's hardly the tip of the iceberg with ADO.NET and the surrounding technologies that you need to know and implement for this type of programming.